# SignalR send intermediate data to client

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

When I issue a SignalR hub method call from the client, I can register to `done` and `fail` promise-callbacks. However, there is a third, practical one, which is `progress`. Can I utilize it somehow to send some kind of intermediate data when the hub operation will take long time? I'd like to keep the `done` callback for the *real* operation result, so I can have a clean client code.

I know I can call whatever client method I want for passing intermediate data, but that's something different, because that's kind of independent from the original server call. I want to have it *bound* to the server call, you'll understand why.

I have a server operation which runs for minutes, I'd like to pass an ID to the client right after calling it, so the client can cancel it for example.

Here is a scratch.

```
...
public async Task<LongOperationResult> SomeLongOperation(string someInputData) {

  var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
  // store the id in a static concurrent dictionary, create a cancellation token source, etc.
  // send the id here to caller's progress callback somehow

  return await Task.Run(() => {
    // do the long processing operation
    return new LongOperationResult() { ... };
  });
}
...
```

On the client side

```
hub.server
  .someLongOperation(myInput)
  .progress(function(id) {
     // do something, bind click event of a Cancel button, etc.
   })
  .done(function(result) {
     // do something with result of type LongOperationResult
   });
```

My real scenario is a bit more complex, allowing multiple tasks to run simultaneously, etc. This is just on example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes it might be a dup thanks, I wonder if I can have `IProgress<object>` to pass strings or ints mixed. But I guess yes, because JS side is dynamic.